# Filepath issues with 'ç' Character in R

Tags: r, filepath

I am having trouble to make R sourcing my functions when trying to use breakpoints. It seems that the trouble is with the special character `ç`, since the filepath spells:

`.../Finanças II/`

The R error message gives:

`Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="...FinanÃ§as II/...": The system cannot find the path specified`

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: as a first hint: check the encoding of the file you are sourcing ...

Comment: What do you mean by encoding? (and sorry if thats obvious...)

Comment: [Character encoding](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Character+encoding)